# R: Request price feed through Bloomberg API

Tags: r, feed, bloomberg

I have just installed the Rbbg package, the Bloomberg API for R. I can't, however, find any documentation. Would someone either be able to point me to some documentation, or, alternatively, give me some guidance w.r.t importing price feeds/data from Bloomberg to R?

Thanks, much appreciated!

Mike

Comment: Found the solution. You have to install Java APIv3 from the Bloomberg terminal (by typing WAPI into the command bar). Once installed you connect it to R using :`install.packages("Rbbg", repos = "http://r.findata.org")` and `conn <-  blpConnect(log.level = "finest")`. Finally, to extract share price information you use `bdp(conn,securities,function)`. Useful manual at http://findata.org/rbloomberg/rbloomberg-manual-0-4-144.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. You have to install Java APIv3 from the Bloomberg terminal (by typing WAPI into the command bar). Once installed you connect it to R using :`install.packages("Rbbg", repos = "http://r.findata.org")` and `conn <-  blpConnect(log.level = "finest")`. Finally, to extract share price information you use `bdp(conn,securities,function)`.

Useful manual at http://findata.org/rbloomberg/rbloomberg-manual-0-4-144.pdf

Comment: They now have a "no-admin" desktop api package. just download the zip, then drag the APIv3 folder to C:\blp\api